# Recursive bruteforce sudoku solver takes too long

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku, brute-force

I'm making a sudoku program, and  I 'created' a recursive algorithm to solve a sudoku. The problem is, that sometimes it works perfectly and in an instant, sometimes it gets stuck and works 10s of seconds, and sometimes I just have to quit it.
Any ideas what might be causing this?

I left the code as it is, since I'm not sure how you answer the question(if you copy and try it out or just check the logic). If you want, I can just write out snippets.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * @Program Sudoku
 * 
 * @date November 2013
 * @hardware MacBook Pro 17", mid 2010, i7, 8GiB RAM
 * @IDE eclipse SDK 4.3.1
 * @purpose generates a valid 9x9 sudoku grid
 *
 */
public class SudokuSolver //seems to werk !!
{
    //create a validitychecker object(will be used as Sudoku.isValid();)
    validityChecker Sudoku = new validityChecker();

    //Create a 2D array where the full sudoku grid will be stored
    private int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

    //Creates a 2D array for the playable sudoku grid (with elements removed)
    private int[][] playingGrid = new int[9][9];

    private Random Ran = new Random();  



    /**
     * @purpose use this construct if you wish to generate a new sudoku
     * @param difficultyLevel removes amount of elements from sudoku using the equation elementToRemove=40+15*difficultyLevel
     */
    SudokuSolver(int difficultyLevel)
    {

            //generate an empty grid
            generateBaseGrid();
            //populate it with a valid sudoku
            solveSudoku(0,0);
            //store this in a new from which elements shall be removed
            for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
                playingGrid[i] = grid[i].clone();               
            //calculate the amount of elements to be removed
            int difficultyMultiplier = 15;
            int baseDifficulty = 40;
            int difficulty = baseDifficulty+difficultyLevel*difficultyMultiplier;

            //and remove them
            removeElements(difficulty);
    }

    /**
     * @purpose use this constructor if you just want to use methods and solve
     * @param the sudoku you wish to solve. values have to be within the range 1-9(inclusive), and -1 for unknown 
     * @note to get the solved sudoku use the fullGrid getter.
     */


    SudokuSolver(int[][] pg)
    {
        //lets clone out the arrays - we don't want to just have references ...
        for(int i = 0; i < pg.length; i++)
            grid[i] = pg[i].clone();    
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
            playingGrid[i] = grid[i].clone();   
        int coords[] = findOnes(grid);
        solveSudoku(coords[0],coords[1]);
        System.out.println(coords[0]+" "+coords[1]);
    }

    /**
     * Use this if you only wish to use the internal methods
     */
    SudokuSolver()
    {}


    //this method was implemented later, and I'm too lazy to change methods that use the procedure, but don't call the method. Maybe in next version
    /**
     * @purpose creates a copy of the passed array
     * @param the array you wish to be copied
     * @return returns a clone of the passed 2D array
     */
    public int[][] cloneBoard(int[][] sudokuArray)
    {
        int[][] result = new int[9][9];
        for(int i = 0; i < sudokuArray.length; i++)
            result[i] = sudokuArray[i].clone();
        return result;
    }


    /*
     *@purpose fills the grid with -1s; This is for proper functionality during validation
     */
    private void generateBaseGrid() 
    {
    //iterates through all the values and stores -1s in it
    for(int r=0;r<9;r++)
        for(int c=0;c<9;c++)
            grid[r][c] = -1;
    //System.out.println("Base Grid Created");
    }



    /**
     * @purpose checks if there are -1s in the grid, if so the grid is playable (its not a solution)
     * @return true if its playable
     */
    public boolean isGridPlayable()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                if(grid[i][j]==-1)
                    return true;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the generated grid with all elements (for one without some  elements use theGrid()) for generator
     * @return the solved grid for solver
     */
    public int[][] fullGrid()
    {

        return grid;

    }

    /**
     * @purpose returns the playing grid
     * @return the playable grid
     */
    public int[][] theGrid()
    {
        return playingGrid;
    }

    /*
     * @purpose removes "amnt" of elements from the playingGrid
     * @return whether the current method was successful
     * @param the amount of elements to be removed
     */
    private boolean removeElements(int amnt)
    {
        if(amnt==0) //yay base case
            return true;
        for(int i=0; i<20;i++)
        {
            int r=Ran.nextInt(9);
            int c=Ran.nextInt(9);

            int element=playingGrid[r][c];

            if(element!=-1)
            {
                playingGrid[r][c]=-1;
                    if(removeElements(amnt-1))
                        {return true;}


            }else{playingGrid[r][c]=element;//removed as per suggestioni--;}
            }
        }
    return false;
    }






    //--------------Debugging--------------------------------
    public void printUserGrid(int[][] printie)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
            int x = printie[i][j];
            String bexp = Integer.toString(x);
            if(x==-1)
                bexp="[]";
            else bexp+=" ";
            System.out.print(bexp+" ");
            if(j==2||j==5)
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        if(i==2||i==5)
            System.out.println();
        }
    }





//  //----------Main only for debugging-----------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SudokuSolver Generator = new SudokuSolver(2);
        int[][] generatedGrid = Generator.theGrid();
        int[][] fullGrid = Generator.fullGrid();
        Generator.printUserGrid(fullGrid);

//      Generator.printUserGrid(generatedGrid);
        System.out.println("\n\n");


        SudokuSolver Solver = new SudokuSolver(generatedGrid);
        Solver.printUserGrid(fullGrid);


    }

}
```

EDIT:
One key thing I forgot to mention, the solveSudoku method, it rearranges some of the values. That means if I'm starting with a **3 it doesn't have a problem returning 312 (this is just an example for illustration). So I'd assume there is some serious logic error somewhere in there.

Comment: I don't think that has something todo with your problem, but in removeElements, you're decrementing i within the for loop. Do never modify the loop counter variable in the body of the loop! This makes it hard to argue about the termination of the loop!

Comment: How about the code to solveSudoku? this is a pretty big problem to be brute forcing. There is some randomness in there too. You may not be doing anything wrong. As an exercise try calculating the size of the recursive tree.

Comment: @isnot2bad: Deleted that, either I just encountered a randomly good set of grids, or it is preforming better now.

Comment: @calrosdc: I just realized I forgot to add one thing - when finding the solution some of the values are rearranged, so let me add that to the description. As for the exercise let me go figure how to do that ;;

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to solve is an `Artificial Intelligence` problem. Going by `brute-force`, or better called plain `backtracking` would actually mean you possibly have an exponential time complexity.

An exponential solution is expected to take long. In some cases where the `order of guesswork` matches the actual solution, your solver will return with a result faster.

So what you can do:

1. Read upon the AI technique called `Constraint Satisfaction`, and try to implement that.
2. Read upon more specific AI sudoku solving techniques, maybe some research paper if there is one and try and implement that.

Answer (score -1):

This is my version of a SudokuSolver:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Sudoku
{
    //This member has been intentionally left public, as the solved sudoku is
    //obtained from here and user will find it much easier to handle this.
    //The Sudoku input has to be given through this instance variable only.
    //Moreover, many a times, Sudoku inputs as an edit-able 2D array is more
    //comfortable than passing a whole 9x9 2D array as a constructor parameter.
    public String SUDOKU[][]=new String[9][9];
    //This variable records the nature of the Sudoku whether solvable or not
    public boolean VALID=true;
    public Sudoku()//this constructor can be used to create SUDOKU objects
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                SUDOKU[i][j]="";
    }
    private Sudoku(String SDK[][])//This is constructor kept private for program use
    {
        SUDOKU=SDK;
    }
    //This function checks if a certain digit is possible in a particular cell
    private boolean isPossible(int n,int i,int j)
    {
        for(int a=i/3*3;a<i/3*3+3;a++)
            for(int b=j/3*3;b<j/3*3+3;b++)
                if(SUDOKU[a][b].length()==1 && n==Integer.parseInt(SUDOKU[a][b]))
                    return false;
        for(int k=0;k<9;k++)
            if(SUDOKU[i][k].length()==1 && n==Integer.parseInt(SUDOKU[i][k]) ||  SUDOKU[k][j].length()==1 && n==Integer.parseInt(SUDOKU[k][j]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    //The following function is compulsory as it is the only function to place appropriate
    //possible digits in the cells of the Sudoku. The easiest Sudokus will get solved here.
    private void fillPossibles()
    {
        boolean newdigit=false;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                if(SUDOKU[i][j].length()!=1)
                {
                    SUDOKU[i][j]="";
                    int count=0;
                    for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
                        if(isPossible(k,i,j))
                        {
                            SUDOKU[i][j]+=k;
                            count++;
                        }
                    if(count==1)
                        newdigit=true;
                }
        if(newdigit)
            fillPossibles();
    }
    //This following function is optional, if the Sudoku is known to be genuine. As,
    //in that case it only increases the solving speed!! But if the nature is not known,
    //this function becomes necessary because the nature of the Sudoku is checked here.
    //It returns true if any cell is filled with a digit and false for all other cases
    private boolean deepFillPossibles(int ai,int aj,int bi,int bj,boolean first)
    {
        if(SUDOKU!=null)
            for(char c='1';c<='9';c++)
            {
                int count=0,digit=0,possibility=0,i=0,j=0;
                boolean valid=true;
                for(int a=ai;a<bi;a++)
                    for(int b=aj;b<bj;b++)
                    {
                        if(SUDOKU[a][b].length()==0)
                            valid=false;
                        for(int k=0;k<SUDOKU[a][b].length();k++)
                            if(SUDOKU[a][b].charAt(k)==c)
                            {
                                if(SUDOKU[a][b].length()>1)
                                {
                                    i=a; j=b; count++;
                                }
                                if(SUDOKU[a][b].length()==1)
                                    digit++;
                                possibility++;
                            }
                    }
                //the following code is executed only if solution() is called first time
                if(first && (digit>1 || valid && possibility==0))
                {
                    SUDOKU=null; return false;
                }
                if(count==1)
                {
                    SUDOKU[i][j]=String.valueOf(c);
                    fillPossibles(); return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
    //This function is also optional if Sudoku is genuine. It only combines the solving
    //power of fillPossibles() and deepFillPossibles() to reduce memory consumption
    //in the next stages. In many cases the Sudoku gets solved at this stage itself.
    private void solution(boolean first)
    {
        fillPossibles();
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(deepFillPossibles(i,0,i+1,9,first) || deepFillPossibles(0,i,9,i+1,first) ||
           deepFillPossibles(i/3*3,i%3*3,i/3*3+3,i%3*3+3,first))
                i=-1;
    }
    //This function is the most challenging. No Sudoku can ever escape solution after
    //passing this stage. It uses ECHO TREE logic implementing brute force to check all
    //kinds of combinations until solution is obtained. It returns a null for no solution.
    private void treeSolution(Tracker track)
    {
        if(SUDOKU==null)
        {
            track.TRACK_SUDOKU=null;
            return;
        }
        solution(false);
        //For a genuine sudoku the statement could have been replaced by "fillPossibles();"
        //(Only it would make solving slower and increase memory consumption!)
        //But it is risky if there is a doubt regarding the genuineness of the Sudoku
        int a=-1,b=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                if(SUDOKU[i][j].length()>1 && a==-1)
                {
                    a=i; b=j;
                }
                else if(SUDOKU[i][j].length()==0)
                    return;
        if(a==-1)//checks if the Sudoku is solved or not setting necessary flags
        {
            track.TRACK_SOLUTION++;
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<9;track.TRACK_SUDOKU[i][j]=SUDOKU[i][j],j++);
            return;
        }
        String temp[][]=new String[9][9];
        for(int k=0;k<SUDOKU[a][b].length();k++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<9;temp[i][j]=SUDOKU[i][j],j++);
            temp[a][b]=String.valueOf(SUDOKU[a][b].charAt(k));
            new Sudoku(temp).treeSolution(track);
            //The following condition stops the braching TREE if the Sudoku is solved by
            //echoing back to the root, depending on the flags set on being solved
            if(track.TRACK_SOLUTION==2 || track.TRACK_SUDOKU==null)
                return;
        }
        return;
    }
    //This is the last function which has public access and can be called by the user.
    //It sets the Sudoku as null if non-genuine and VALIDity as false if no unique solution
    public void solve()
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<9;SUDOKU[i][8]=SUDOKU[i][8],SUDOKU[8][i]=SUDOKU[8][i],i++);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            SUDOKU=null; VALID=false; return;
        }
        Tracker track=new Tracker();
        solution(true);
        treeSolution(track);
        SUDOKU=track.TRACK_SOLUTION==0?null:track.TRACK_SUDOKU;
        if(track.TRACK_SOLUTION!=1)
            VALID=false;
    }
}

//the following class is purposely designed to easily track the changes during solution,
//including the nature of the Sudoku and the solution of the Sudoku(if possible)

class Tracker
{
    protected int TRACK_SOLUTION=0;
    protected String TRACK_SUDOKU[][]=new String[9][9];
}

public class SudokuSolver extends JApplet implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    private String SUDOKU[][]=new String[9][9];
    private Sudoku SDK=new Sudoku();
    private Image BOX[][]=new Image[9][9],SELECT_IMG;//BOX is an array of square images
    private int SELECT_ROW=4,SELECT_COLUMN=4;//stores the position of the selection box
    //this function is used to initialize the coloured square images and fonts
    public void init()
    {
        resize(190,190);
        setFont(new Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,12));
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Graphics g;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;SUDOKU[i][j]="",j++)
            {
                BOX[i][j]=createImage(22,22);
                g=BOX[i][j].getGraphics();
                if((i/3+j/3)%2==0)
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillRect(0,0,21,21);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(0,0,21,21);
            }
        //the following statements colour the selection box red
        SELECT_IMG=createImage(22,22);
        g=SELECT_IMG.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0,0,21,21);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0,0,21,21);
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    //the following function handles the mouse click operations
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(SDK.SUDOKU==null)
        {
            SDK.SUDOKU=new String[9][9];
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<9;SUDOKU[i][j]="",SDK.SUDOKU[i][j]="",j++);
            SDK.VALID=true;
        }
        if(e.getY()<190 && e.getX()<190 && e.getY()%21!=0 && e.getX()%21!=0)
        {
            SELECT_ROW=e.getY()/21;
            SELECT_COLUMN=e.getX()/21;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
    //this function manages the operations associated with the various keys
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int code=e.getKeyCode();
        if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE || code==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || code==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]=""; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="";
        }
        switch(code)
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_Y : if(SDK.SUDOKU!=null) SDK.VALID=true; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP : SELECT_ROW=(SELECT_ROW+8)%9; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN : SELECT_ROW=(SELECT_ROW+1)%9; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : SELECT_COLUMN=(SELECT_COLUMN+8)%9; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT : SELECT_COLUMN=(SELECT_COLUMN+1)%9; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER : SDK.solve(); break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_N : if(SDK.SUDOKU!=null){ SDK.VALID=true; code=KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE;}
            case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE : if(SDK.SUDOKU==null)
                                      {
                                          SDK.SUDOKU=new String[9][9];
                                          for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                                              for(int j=0;j<9;SUDOKU[i][j]="",SDK.SUDOKU[i][j]="",j++);
                                          SDK.VALID=true;
                                      }
                                      else
                                          for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                                              for(int j=0;j<9;SDK.SUDOKU[i][j]=SUDOKU[i][j],j++);
        }
        repaint();
    }
    //this function is for entering the numbers in the sudoku grid
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        char code=e.getKeyChar();
        if(Character.isDigit(code))
            switch(code)
            {
                case '1': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="1"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="1"; break;
                case '2': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="2"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="2"; break;
                case '3': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="3"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="3"; break;
                case '4': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="4"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="4"; break;
                case '5': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="5"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="5"; break;
                case '6': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="6"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="6"; break;
                case '7': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="7"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="7"; break;
                case '8': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="8"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="8"; break;
                case '9': SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="9"; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="9"; break;
                default : SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]=""; SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN]="";
            }
    }
    //the paint() function is designed to print the the sudoku grid and other messages
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(!SDK.VALID)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(1,1,188,188);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(0,0,189,189);
            if(SDK.SUDOKU==null)
            {
                g.drawString("INVALID SUDOKU!!",45,80);
                g.drawString("[PRESS ESCAPE TO RE-ENTER]",10,105);
            }
            else
            {
                g.drawString("INCOMPLETE SUDOKU!!",30,60);
                g.drawString("Would you like to see a",30,90);
                g.drawString("possible solution?",45,105);
                g.drawString("Y / N",80,120);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                {
                    g.drawImage(BOX[i][j],j*21,i*21,null);
                    g.drawString(SDK.SUDOKU[i][j],8+j*21,15+i*21);
                }
            g.drawImage(SELECT_IMG,SELECT_COLUMN*21,SELECT_ROW*21,null);
            g.drawString(SDK.SUDOKU[SELECT_ROW][SELECT_COLUMN],8+SELECT_COLUMN*21,15+SELECT_ROW*21);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use minimum brute force wherever possible